# Flatten a json column containing multiple comma separated json in spark dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flatten

In my spark dataframe I have a column which contains a single json having multiple comma separated json having key value pair. Need to faltten the json data in different columns.

The record of json column student_data looks like below

```
+--+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id|name  |student_data                                                                                                                           |     
+--+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|11|stephy|{{"key":"hindi","value":{"hindi_mythology":80}},{"key":"social_science","value":{"civics":65}},{"key":"maths","value":{"geometry":70}}}|
+--+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Schema of record is as below.

```
root
|-- id : int
|-- name : string
|-- student_data : string
```

The requirement is to flatten the json as expected output is as below.

```
+-----------+-----+--------------+------+
|id |name   |hindi|social_science|maths |
+---+-------+-----+--------------+------+
|1  |stephy |80   |65            |70    |
+---+-------+-----+-----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Can you put that row on json format, it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your json into a struct type using spark function from_json() using a schema that represent the schema of the json string, after that to get the expected results you can pivot the column to go from rows into column format:

The input jdon file:

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "name": "stephy",
  "student_data": "[{\"key\":\"hindi\",\"value\":{\"hindi_mythology\":80}},{\"key\":\"social_science\",\"value\":{\"civics\":65}},{\"key\":\"maths\",\"value\":{\"geometry\":70}}]"
}
```

Code:

```
val df = spark.read.json("file.json")
val schema = new StructType()
  .add("key", StringType, true)
  .add("value", MapType(StringType, IntegerType), true)

val res = df.withColumn("student_data", from_json(col("student_data"), ArrayType(schema)))
  .select(col("id"), col("name"), explode(col("student_data")).as("student_data"))
  .select("id", "name", "student_data.*")
  .select(col("id"), col("name"), col("key"), map_values(col("value")).getItem(0).as("value"))

res.groupBy("id", "name").pivot("key").agg(first(col("value"))).show(false)

+---+------+-----+-----+--------------+
|id |name  |hindi|maths|social_science|
+---+------+-----+-----+--------------+
|11 |stephy|80   |70   |65            |
+---+------+-----+-----+--------------+
```